# how to apply a function to all rows in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

Consider for example the function "norm". I have a matrix, and I want to apply "norm" to each row in the matrix, and get a vector of all norms for each row in this matrix.

I was hoping I could do norm(A, 'rows'), but that is not possible. Is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it without converting to a cell array:

```
arrayfun(@(n) norm(A(n,:)), 1:size(A,1))
```

Comment: +1 Easier and apparently faster than converting to cell.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
M = 1e4;
N = 1e3;
A = randn(M, N);

% Solve
B = mat2cell(A, ones(M, 1), N);
b = cellfun(@norm, B);
```

Maybe arrayfun could be used instead?